# Rendering HTML in web.py

Tags: python, html, templates, web.py

I am handling with a Wikipedia-like project. I can convert the text file to html code using the markdown. My problem is, I want to render this html code in a html file. Here is my code,

```
class articles:
    def GET(self):
        form_name=web.input()
        article_name=form_name.page
        article_file_path=os.path.join('articles',article_name)
        fp = open(article_file_path,'rU')
        text = fp.read()
        body = markdown2.markdown(text)
        return render.article_files(article_name, body)
```

I'm passing article_name and body(html code) to article_files.html. The body looks like,

```
<h1>Hai</h1>
<p>Welcome<em>Ajay</em></p>
```

The problem is, the body displays as it is. That is the html code is printed in the screen with all tags. I want to render this html code (body) like,

**Hai**
Welcome  *Ajay*

My HTML file is:

```
$def with(title,content)
<html>
<head>
<title>$title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" method="GET">
        $content
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTML escaping is on by default in web.py templates. To turn it off, prepend the variable name with a colon:

```
<form name="form" method="GET">
    $:content
</form>
```

Make sure there is no way for a potentially malicious user to feed arbitrary HTML into your unescaped templates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the [mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) of the date you are sending to the browser, otherwise it doesn't know how to display it.

You can do this by adding the [following line](http://webpy.org/reference/web.header) to your function:

```
web.header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ajay is talking about the _body_ (i.e., `h1` and `p`) being rendered verbatim, not the whole page.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Even if just the body was not being rendered, this is still helpful. Solved my problem, upvoted.